# Variable scope in OOP

Tags: php

I've got the classes in my structure:

```
require_once("classes/config.php");
require_once("classes/database.php");
require_once("classes/template.php");
require_once("classes/route.php");
require_once("classes/user.php");


$config = new config;
$route = new route();
$db = new database ($config['db_host'], $config['db_name'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_pasw']);
```

Class 'template' uses template files.
What is the right way to work with database or user class, for example, in the template class?

How it's working now:

```
global $user;
```

But it's not 'good coding practices', right?

Comment: No. Using `require_once` is not a good practice. Doing computation in the constructor is not a god practice. Making a database wrapper class is not a good practice. Using a class, when you want an array is not OOP. And using global state is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

So, in `User` class you can do something like this object-oriented way:

```
class User{
    private $user;

    public function getUser(){
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

And to get user in your script,

```
$userObj = new User();

$user = $userObj->getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection.

Collect the data that you want to render in your template in a data set that will be injected into the template render function, like:

```
// This can be class or array, as you prefer
$viewData = array(
    'user' => $user,
    'something_else' => ...
);

$template = new Template('id');
$template->render($viewData);
```

Comment: What if I want to get the query from the database class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's not very good.
You can specify the connection variables in a separate configuration class.
Then, connect it to the constructor where necessary and use it.
Thus, there will not be a single global variable in your project.

Here is an example. But you must know. It's a bicycle, just for example. But here there is no DI (Dependency injection):

Config

```
namespace Model;

class ConfigModel
{
    public $db =   'name_db';
    public $user = 'user_u';
    public $pass = '123456';

    public $protocol = 'https:';
    public $brand = 'MyBrand.com';
    public $salt = 'ougfhdsihgsugsdopgf';

    public $path = __DIR__;
}
```

DB class

```
namespace Model;

class DB
{
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $db =   '';
    protected $charset = 'utf8';
    protected $user = '';
    protected $pass = '';

    public function __construct() {

        $config = new ConfigModel();
        $this->db = $config->db;
        $this->user = $config->user;
        $this->pass = $config->pass;


        $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db;charset=$this->charset";
        $opt = array(
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );

        try {
            $this->DBconnect = new \PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $opt);
        }
        catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
            echo $Exception->getMessage();
            echo $Exception->getCode();
            if(!empty($Exception->getCode())){
                die('Error');
            }
        }
    }

    public function showAllUser() {
        $db = $this->DBconnect->prepare('SELECT `mail` FROM `users`');
        $db->execute();
        return $db->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, doyou want to render global the user information like as, for example, the name of the user?I think the correct way to use the user details or the login details is using $_SESSION and after with $_SESSION['user'] you can render the user details in template.

Comment: I want to get the access from the one class to another. For example, render the of the user or get the information from database via DB class.